# Socket travado ao realizar troca de dados

Tags: java, socket

Estou tentando realizar código de servidor e cliente em Java para o cliente enviar uma `String`, o servidor processar e devolver ela e o cliente receber.

O cliente é mantido sempre escutando.

Mas apos receber a `String` ele trava.

Classe servidor

```
// porta do servidor
    int serverDoor = 4000;

    // numero maximo de conexões que o servidor aceita
    int maxConnections = 10;

    // servidor socket
    ServerSocket server = null;

    // conexão socket
    Socket connection = null;

    // saida dos dados
    OutputStream output = null;

    // entrada dos dados
    InputStream input = null;

    try {

            server = new ServerSocket(serverDoor, maxConnections);

            while (true) {

            System.out.println("Esperando cliente");

            connection = server.accept();

            // abrindo o stream de saida
            output = connection.getOutputStream();
            output.flush();

            // abrindo o stream de entrada
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

            // recebendo
            String teste = bufferedReader.readLine();

            output.write("Teste".getBytes());
            output.flush();

        }

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } finally {

        try {

            if (output != null) {
                output.close();
            }

            if (input != null) {
                input.close();
            }

            if (connection != null) {
                connection.close();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }           
}
```

Classe cliente

```
Socket client;
OutputStream output;
InputStream input;

// Step 1: Create a Socket to make connection
client = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(url), porta);
//client.setSoTimeout(15000); // 5 segundos

// Step 2: Get the input and output streams
output = client.getOutputStream();
output.flush();
input = client.getInputStream();

// Step 3: Process connection
output.write(msg.getBytes());
output.flush();

// recebendo
System.out.println("Antes de receber cliente");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
int temp;
while ((temp = input.read()) > -1)
    sb.append((char) temp);
System.out.println("Depois de receber cliente");

// Step 4: Close connection
if (output != null)
    output.close();
if (input != null)
    input.close();
if (client != null)
    client.close();

return sb.toString();
```

}

Após o método de receber a String ele para, eu uso Windows 8, não sei se isso pode representar algo.

Comment: Por quê `new ServerSocket(serverDoor, maxConnections)` está dentro de um loop infinito?

Comment: @pepper_chico arrumei mas ainda da o problema.

Comment: Onde está `msg`, a mensagem que você envia? Como não vejo, não sei se há um end-of-line nela, já que o server faz um `readLine()` e vai esperar que o end-of-line chegue.

Comment: @pepper_chico ela vem como parâmetro, é um método de classe estática o cliente.

Comment: A questão é, ela tem um end-of-line?

Comment: `write` no cliente vai enviar dados sem adicionar end-of-line extra, e o servidor faz `readLine()`.

Comment: @pepper_chico desculpe, mas eu não entendi muito bem oq vc quis dizer, poderia responder com o código editado por favor? Eu alterei o método para `readline` pois achei na net e parecia ser mais simples que o laço do cliente.

Comment: entenda end-of-line como `'\n'`. O seu servidor diz que entende um fim de uma mensagem com este caractere, pois você usa um `readLine`. Mas no cliente você envia dados via `write` que tão somente vai escrever os caracteres que você requisitar, e se não houver um `'\n'` seu servidor vai ficar esperando por um. Se houver um método `writeLine`, este vai acrescentar um `'\n'` pra você.

Comment: @pepper_chico entendi, conversando com objetos diferentes se assim posso dizer.

Comment: veja as dicas __e comentários__ nas outras respostas também.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa fechar o *output* no servidor para que o cliente entenda que acabou a mensagem:

```
// recebendo
String teste = bufferedReader.readLine();

output.write("Teste".getBytes());
output.flush();
output.close();
```

E o servidor também pode travar se o cliente não retornar um \n no final da mensagem de acordo com a documentação do [BufferedReader#readLine()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29)

```
// Step 3: Process connection
output.write(msg.getBytes());
output.write('\n');
output.flush();
```

Uma sugestão para melhorar seu código seria utilizar `PrintWriter` e `BufferedReader` no cliente e no servidor. Você está utilizando formas diferentes de leitura e escrita.

Aqui tem um [exemplo detalhado](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html).

Comment: Não é preciso "fechar output", basta haver o envio de "end-of-line". TCP tem a intenção de ser útil para conexões permanentes, portanto não é preciso ficar abrindo e fechando conexões quando não é necessário.

Comment: Neste caso é necessário fechar o output, pois a parte do cliente não está esperando um "end-of-line". No entanto, como eu disse anteriormente, a parte servidor espera o "end-of-line".

Comment: Você está dizendo que é **necessário**  dar `close` previamente em `output` na parte cliente (note que ele faz isso ao final), para que então seja possível ter o envio de dados? Sei lá como funciona essa parte Java, não programo Java mas conheço TCP de outras linguagens e isso não faz muito sentido pra mim.

Comment: Estou dizendo que é **necessário** dar `close` no `output` na parte **servidor** (coisa que ele não faz no servidor, pois o servidor fica em loop infinito escutando por clientes), para que então seja possível que o cliente _pare de tentar receber_.

Comment: Não exatamente isto, não é necessário dar `close`, mais próprio é dizer que necessário reestruturar a comunicação, ele está em loop fazendo `accept`. Uma conexão obtida através de `accept` anteriormente poderia dar continuidade de comunicação paralelamente enquanto ele continua aceitando mais clientes. Mas de fato, a inexistência de `close` em qualquer parte do servidor indica um problema mas não o impediria por completo de receber comunicação.

Comment: Concordo totalmente, mas, como a solução dele não exige continuidade de comunicação, preferi não entrar em maiores detalhes! Abs!

Comment: @vrcca poderia me dizer porque desta sua sugestão de melhoria por favor?

Comment: Para ter uniformidade (além de facilidade de manutenção e leitura) na implementação de comunicação entre cliente e servidor. Por exemplo, no cliente você está tratando diretamente com bytes, enquanto seria muito mais simples tratar com Strings através das classes BufferedReader e PrintWriter (além de ter melhor tratamento com múltiplas threads, etc).

Answer (score 2):

Na classe servidor o fechamento do stream de saída (output) está num local impróprio, o finally. Esse finally somente será executado quando o escopo do try chegar ao fim, ou seja, quando o looping finalizar, mas ele é infinito, e "nunca" será fechado e por esse motivo o client "trava".

O client fica "travado", ou melhor, aguardando mais bytes nesse trecho:

```
...
// recebendo
System.out.println("Antes de receber cliente");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
int temp;
while ((temp = input.read()) > -1)
        sb.append((char) temp);
System.out.println("Depois de receber cliente");
...
```

A única condição de termino do `while` é `read()` retornar -1 (ou menor), o que normalmente só vai ocorrer quando houver um fim de stream de dados via `close()` no servidor (e problemas de rede, etc). Assim, a chamada do método input.read() congela, pois o output do server ainda está aberto e como consequência o input do client fica aguardando mais dados e se tem a impressão que "travou";

Por fim, o intuito do looping nessa questão é tratar uma conexão para cada client, como por consequência o input e output são instanciados a cada accept() da instância de ServerSocket e por isso devem ser fechados a cada iteração. Para tal pode-se fechar a connection, pois ela se encarregará de fechar tudo que estiver pendente.

Seguindo esse raciocínio o código fonte para o server ficaria assim:

```
// porta do servidor
int serverDoor = 4000;

// numero maximo de conexões que o servidor aceita
int maxConnections = 10;

// servidor socket
ServerSocket server = null;

try {

    server = new ServerSocket(serverDoor, maxConnections);

    while (true) {

        System.out.println("Esperando cliente");

        // conexão socket, dentro do looping
        Socket connection = null;

        // saida dos dados, dentro do looping
        OutputStream output = null;

        // aceitando a conexão
        connection = server.accept();

        // abrindo o stream de saida
        output = connection.getOutputStream();
        output.flush();

        // abrindo o stream de entrada
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

        // recebendo
        String teste = bufferedReader.readLine();

        output.write("Teste".getBytes());
        output.flush();

        // fechando tudo!
        connection.close();
    }

} catch (IOException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();

}
```

Comment: +1, tip: adicionar nota que... o cliente está esperando um fim de stream _ao checar por -1_, _portanto_ e por causa dessa forma de trabalho, o servidor precisa terminar a stream via `close`, o que não implica que todo servidor TCP precisa dar `close` para cada mensagem enviada, basta o cliente entender fim-de-mensagem que não seja fim-de-stream.